# Asp.net MVC 4 Create View - Ordering Drop Down for Forgein Key table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an MVC4 project using EF6 to which I have added a Controller, Model and related Views using the VS 2012 wizard.

The Create View includes this code (.aspx engine)

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.senProviderId, "Site Id") %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList("senProviderId", String.Empty) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.senProviderId) %>
    </div>
```

where model.senProviderId references a related (foreign key) table and produces this HTML (segment)

```
        <div class="editor-field">
        <select id="senProviderId" name="senProviderId"><option value=""></option>
        <option value="3">SW127     </option>
        <option value="4">NE011     </option>
        <option value="5">NE133     </option>
        <option value="6">Out016    </option>
        .....
        <option value="104">SE133     </option>
        </select>
```

For obvious reasons I need to order the Drop-Down by the Display Value rather then by the underlying key.

How can that best be done?

EDIT: As requested Controller code for the parent table Controller

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.senHousingCode = new SelectList(db.sssHousingCodes, "hcId", "hcName");
        ViewBag.senProviderId = new SelectList(db.sssProviderProfiles, "prvId", "prvSiteId");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please share the related Controller code where you are initializing the Model/Providers.

Comment: Good point thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OF course - I was looking for decoration on the Model but of course the answer is using OrderBy in the controller code:

```
 ViewBag.senProviderId = new SelectList(db.sssProviderProfiles.OrderBy(m => m.prvSiteId), "prvId", "prvSiteId");
```

thanks for the prompt Mikhail!